# Incorrect syntax near Error

Tags: c#

Source:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string bn = "select * from Planilha where ROTA=" + dtExcel.Rows[i][0];
    SqlCommand Queryyy = new SqlCommand(bn, conexao);
    SqlDataReader drr;
    drr = Queryyy.ExecuteReader();
    if (drr.Read() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Planilha SET LOJA ='" + dtExcel.Rows[i][1] + "' where ROTA = " + dtExcel.Rows[i][0] + ")", conexao);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro1 " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

to finding the `dtExcel.Rows[i][0]` is not sending update

---

```
 string cmdText = "insert into Planilha3 (ROTALOJ,....) values(@p0+@p1,@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15,@p16,@p17,@p18,@p19,@p20,@p21,@p22,@p23,@p24,@p25,@p26,@p27,@p28,@p29,@p30,@p31,@p32,@p33,@p34,@p35,@p36,@p37,@p38,@p39,@p40,@p41,@p42,@p43,@p44,@p45,@p46,@p47,@48,@p49,@50,@51,@52,@53,@54,@55,@56,@57,@58,@p59,@p60,@p61,@p62)";
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conexao);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", dtExcel.Rows[i][0]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dtExcel.Rows[i][1]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dtExcel.Rows[i][2]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", dtExcel.Rows[i][3]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", dtExcel.Rows[i][4]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", dtExcel.Rows[i][5]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", dtExcel.Rows[i][6]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", dtExcel.Rows[i][7]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", dtExcel.Rows[i][8]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", dtExcel.Rows[i][9]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", dtExcel.Rows[i][10]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", dtExcel.Rows[i][11]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", dtExcel.Rows[i][12]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", dtExcel.Rows[i][13]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p14", dtExcel.Rows[i][14]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p15", dtExcel.Rows[i][15]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p16", dtExcel.Rows[i][16]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p17", dtExcel.Rows[i][17]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p18", dtExcel.Rows[i][18]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p19", dtExcel.Rows[i][19]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p20", dtExcel.Rows[i][20]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p21", dtExcel.Rows[i][21]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p22", dtExcel.Rows[i][22]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p23", dtExcel.Rows[i][23]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p24", dtExcel.Rows[i][24]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p25", dtExcel.Rows[i][25]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p26", dtExcel.Rows[i][26]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p27", dtExcel.Rows[i][27]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p28", dtExcel.Rows[i][28]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p29", dtExcel.Rows[i][29]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p30", dtExcel.Rows[i][30]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p31", dtExcel.Rows[i][31]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p32", dtExcel.Rows[i][32]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p33", dtExcel.Rows[i][33]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p34", dtExcel.Rows[i][34]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p35", dtExcel.Rows[i][35]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p36", dtExcel.Rows[i][36]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p37", dtExcel.Rows[i][37]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p38", dtExcel.Rows[i][38]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p39", dtExcel.Rows[i][39]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p40", dtExcel.Rows[i][40]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p41", dtExcel.Rows[i][41]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p42", dtExcel.Rows[i][42]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p43", dtExcel.Rows[i][43]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p44", dtExcel.Rows[i][44]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p45", dtExcel.Rows[i][45]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p46", dtExcel.Rows[i][46]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p47", dtExcel.Rows[i][47]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p48", dtExcel.Rows[i][48]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p49", dtExcel.Rows[i][49]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p50", dtExcel.Rows[i][50]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p51", dtExcel.Rows[i][51]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p52", dtExcel.Rows[i][52]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p53", dtExcel.Rows[i][53]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p54", dtExcel.Rows[i][54]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p55", dtExcel.Rows[i][55]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p56", dtExcel.Rows[i][56]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p57", dtExcel.Rows[i][57]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p58", dtExcel.Rows[i][58]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p59", dtExcel.Rows[i][59]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p60", dtExcel.Rows[i][60]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p61", dtExcel.Rows[i][61]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p62", dtExcel.Rows[i][62]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p63", dtExcel.Rows[i][63]);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Erro2 " + ex.Message);
                        continue;
                    }
```

[image]

is now giving this error

Comment: What is `dtExcel` ? and what is the type of `dtExcel.Rows`?

Comment: What is `dtExcel.Rows[i][0]` exactly when you debug your code? And please use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, the syntax error is caused by the close parenthesys at the end of the update query

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Planilha SET LOJA ='" + dtExcel.Rows[i][1] + 
                   "' where ROTA = " + dtExcel.Rows[i][0] , conexao);
                                                         ^^^ removed
```

However this code is really asking for troubles.

You need to start using parameterized queries to avoid possible syntax errors when in your input texts appear one or more single quotes that break your string concatenation.
And, more important, to avoid Sql Injections

So, for example, the inner update code becomes

```
string cmdText = "UPDATE Planilha SET LOJA =@p1 where ROTA = @p2";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conexao);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dtExcel.Rows[i][1]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dtExcel.Rows[i][0].ToString());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

while the first query becomes

```
string bn = "select * from Planilha where ROTA=@p1";
SqlCommand Queryyy = new SqlCommand(bn, conexao);
Queryyy.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dtExcel.Rows[i][0]);
....
```

At this point there is just a problem to resolve. What is the datatype of the column ROTA?
If it is a numeric type then you need to convert the value obtained from `dtExcel` to a numeric value.

For example in case of integers

```
Queryyy.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Convert.ToInt32(dtExcel.Rows[i][0]));
```